# Can green goo discharged from cables through PVC and copper reaction be cleaned by electrical contact cleaner?

Tags: wire, cleaning

I have an old power supply but the wires have a green slime (goo) discharge running through it and in the pins as well, I want to clean it so it can have good conductivity, however, after researching, I found that the green discharge is caused by the decomposing plasticizer and the copper of the PVC cable. I have pictures of the green goo :

[image]

[image]

I'm worried if I spray the Q22 electrical contact cleaner it might cause a flame.
At the bottom of the picture, are the ingredients of the contact cleaner I have :

[image]

**Is it safe to clean it by using this spray? if not, how to clean those green slime liquid?**

Comment: try isopropyl alcohol

Comment: @jsotola I don't have access to isopropyl alcohol 99% as it isn't allowed to pass through the customs of the country : (  any other alternative?

Comment: you cannot buy isopropyl alcohol at a drug store?

Comment: @jsotola there's only a 70% isopropyl alcohol available in pharmacy, will that do?

Comment: @JohnSall Better than nothing. Or wood stove alcohol from the hardware store, but super toxic depending on whether its methanol or denatured ethanol. You don't want methanol that pure touching your skin and common gloves only provide limited protection against it.

Comment: use the cleaner then ... the propellant is probably flammable, so do not use near flame ... use outside and wait a few seconds to let the solvent evaporate before bringing inside the house

Comment: the 70% alcohol would work ... it may leave an oily residue because it is intended for use on skin ... the oil keeps skin from drying out ... test it on paper ... the 30% may be oil or water or both

Comment: @JohnSall If the isoprop is only 70% and you are not in North America then it very well may have that nasty "rubbing oil" added to it. Here, when I buy 70% or 91% it's just water that is added. No oil. But I've heard that's not the case in many other areas of the world. (I've no real clue, though.) And do check out how well it dissolves in whatever solution you try -- easy test to do.

Comment: @JohnSall I can't help it. There's chemist cleaners bursting to mind from past years in labs:  (1) add sodium or potassium hydroxide, solid tablet form, to your isoprop or ethanol to boost it; (2) just use some nice dilute 2% hydrofluoric acid -- briefly!; (3) the old standby of 1:3 nitric to hydrochloric acids, aqua regia; (4) sulfuric acid (98%) added to potassium dichromate (just toss some in) for chromerge!; (5) piranha solution from 98% H2SO4 and 30% H2O2 -- watch yourself with this; (6) if 98% H2SO4 isn't cutting it, make it 115% and add sulfur trioxide! Poly is good!

Comment: @JohnSall If the green goop stands up to those suggestions, sell it to chemists as containment liner. You'll make a bundle.